# > all ( ) vs max () efficiency and speed of processing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Both  `>all()` and the `Max()` in SQL server may give the same result but i need to know if there is any technical difference the 2 and how does both affect the efficiency of processing in terms of accuracy and time/speed

Comment: The answer to almost every performance question in T-SQL is "it depends; get the query execution plans and compare". This one is no different. The optimizer is clever enough to know to rewrite `>= ALL (...)` expressions into a `MAX` aggregate in at least one case I tried, but that says little about *your* queries. To a first approximation, use what makes your query obvious to read. (To that point, the `ALL` operator is relatively under-used and obscure.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply !I am not a professional about this issue but its just that other things like for example when using the " IN" keyword I read over the internet that its less efficient where its possible to use the key "Exists" instead since the later doesn't need to go through all the records for comparison thus less st work for the processor so I thought that it maybe the same case for the "All()" and "Max()" thing according to their corresponding techniques